# SwiftUI not compiling with «The compiler is unable to type-check this expression...» error

Tags: xcode, swiftui

I'm trying to build a huge amount of SwiftUI code that was working a week ago, but now it's just building for 10+ mins, and then just gives this error:

```
The compiler is unable to type-check this expression in reasonable time; try breaking up the expression into distinct sub-expressions
```

The code is really huge, so I upload it to GitHub Gist: [link](https://gist.github.com/itslequid/e9f7b1ac65032055ed3823da5c72c47d)

It gives error on this line:

```
    var body: some View {
    NavigationView { <––––––––– error on this line
        ZStack {
```

I'm using XCode Version 11.5 (11E608c)

Comment: The compiler is telling you what to do. Your view is indeed really huge. It's definitely not the right way to go. The best practice is to break down the View into small parts with each sub-view responsible only for a handful of things.

Comment: It looks we will never cure this - MVC is still alive - but as ... "Massive" View Content ))